# Quisiera que no se me repitieran las posiciones de los corredores

Tags: javascript, html5, array

Lo que quise hacer en este código fue tratar de poder **generar aleatoriamente posiciones** para así poder concatenar cada jugador con cada una de ellas, para luego mostrar por consola pero... el detalle.. bien grande de paso! es que **se me repiten las posiciones**.

O sea, *los números aleatorios se me repiten* y no encuentro la forma de que no se me repitan.

```javascript
var jugadores = ["carlos","luis","manuel","daniel","Sofia"];

let posiciones = [];

let min = 0;

let max = 5;

for(i=1; i<=jugadores.length; i++){
    posiciones = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min));
    
    console.log(posiciones +" "+ jugadores[i]);
};
```

Comment: ¿ya intentaste usar set o memorización? Si esos enfoques son muy triviales para tí también podrías intentar hacer un sendero hamiltoniano poniendole seilla a tu random en base a los índices de jugadores.

Comment: *"Los números aleatorios se me repiten"* -> Es que si no se repitiesen no serían aleatorios, no crees?? :) Por cierto... en cuanto a lo de no encontrar la forma de que no se repitan... has probado a mirar si ya está el número en el array antes de meterlo?? Es bastante obvio que si metes el mismo número dos veces va a estar repetido... pero si en vez de meterlo, buscas otro, pues no va a haber repetidos

Comment: Pues si pero me estuve matando la cabeza de poder intentar plasmar esa condicion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo así:

```js
let jugadores = ["carlos","luis","manuel","daniel","Sofia"];

let numjugadores = jugadores.length;

let posiciones = [];

while(posiciones.length < numjugadores){
    let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * numjugadores) ;
    if(posiciones.indexOf(r) === -1) posiciones.push(r);
}

for(i=0; i<=numjugadores-1; i++){
    console.log(posiciones[i] +" "+ jugadores[i]);
}
```

De este modo primero creas el *array* de las **posiciones** de forma aleatoria, y después tan solo debes recorrerlo con los jugadores.

**Explicación línea a línea:**

- Establecemos una variable de tipo array con los jugadores

```javascript
let jugadores = ["carlos","luis","manuel","daniel","Sofia"];
```

- Establecemos una variable numérica contando los elementos de la anterior variable de jugadores, para un uso posterior más cómodo, mediante la función `length`:

```javascript
let numjugadores = jugadores.length;
```

- Inicializamos una variable de tipo array para su uso posterior dentro del bucle siguiente:

```javascript
let posiciones = [];
```

- Creamos un bucle cuya condición va a ser que mientras los elementos de la variable `posiciones` sean menores que la cantidad de jugadores en total, establecida anteriormente en la variable `numjugadores`, las iteraciones se vayan repitiendo.

```javascript
while(posiciones.length < numjugadores){
```

- Dentro del bucle establecemos una variable denominada `r`, que se ira sobreescribiendo en cada iteración, que contendrá el resultado del cálculo aleatorio de las posiciones (del 1 al 5 solamente)  mediante la fórmula matemática `Math.random()`:

```javascript
let r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * numjugadores) ;
```

Esta fórmula anterior es una adaptación de [la función `getRandomInt`  que aparece en la documentación de Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

- El condicional `if` siguiente calcula la posición del valor de `r` (obtenido en el cálculo de la línea anterior) dentro del array `posiciones`.  Si este valor aun no está en el array posiciones, es decir, si vale `-1`, entonces se agrega al array mediante la función `push`.

```javascript
if(posiciones.indexOf(r) === -1) posiciones.push(r);
```

En caso contrario, es decir, si `posiciones.indexOf(r)` tiene cualquier otro valor, querrá decir que ya estamos usando ese número de posición, y como **no queremos repetirlo** no lo agregamos con `push` y saltamos a la siguiente iteración.

- A continuación simplemente cerramos el `while`

```javascript
}
```

- En este punto ya hemos conseguido crear un array, `posiciones` con los 5 valores aleatorios distintos que van del 1 al 5, ordenados tal como fueron encontrados aleatoriamente. Por lo tanto lo que hacemos ahora es recorrer ambos arrays con datos, que son `posiciones` y `jugadores`, mediante un bucle for que iterará un total de `numjugadores`, pero como necesitamos empezar de 0 (porque los indices de array empiezan por 0), establecemos el inicio en 0 (`i = 0`) y le restamos uno al total de `numjugadores` (`i<=numjugadores-1`), quedando asi:

```javascript
for(i=0; i<=numjugadores-1; i++){
```

- Luego ya mostramos por consola la posible correlación entre ambos arrays de datos, usando `i` como número de indice en ambas, pues el array `posiciones` ya fue generado aleatoriamente antes, y era lo que nos interesaba conseguir:

```javascript
console.log(posiciones[i] +" "+ jugadores[i]);
```

- Y finalmente cerramos el bucle:

```javascript
}
```

Comment: Bendito RNG, estuve a punto de ponerte un downvote porque en 5 ejecuciones, el 3 siempre salió exactamente en mitad del array. Tal vez debería jugar a la lotería hoy!

Comment: No te creas, tambien he tenido mis dudas... a mi me salio el 4 muchas veces con el primer nombre al principio :-)   pero nada, es que son muy pocos numeros... supongo que si lo ejecutamos 1000 veces la media entre todos mejora. La formula la saque de la pagina de Math.random pero un poco adaptada a lo que ya tenia el OP (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: masterguru esa condición que pusiste hay en el if como se puede leer por qué pusiste === -1 y quedo como en duda ósea se que sirve para que no se repitan las posiciones pero no entiendo como lo hace pues

Comment: Esa condición busca la posición actual en el indice del array ese valor aleatorio creado con la función aleatoria (que va del 1 al 5 en este caso). Si no existe, es decir, si vale `-1` entonces la agrega con un `push`, y si existe sigue el while hasta que se cumpla la condición del while, es decir, que haya 5 elementos.  Quizas se pega 1000 iteraciones como 10 para llegar a los 5 del while, eso da igual, la cuestion es que si el valor del 1 al 5 encontrado ya existe repetirá la iteración.  Quizas me he explicado mal esta vez, pero es asi :-)

Comment: Dicho de otro modo, la funcion `posiciones.indexOf(r)` devuelve `-1` cuando no encuentra `r` entre los valores del array  `posiciones` que estamos creando.

Comment: @DanielZabala Ale, acabo de amplicar mi respuesta con una detallada explicación.  Espero que sea suficiente para que lo entiendas.

Comment: No mas bien gracias, perfecta explicacion yo como te digo estaba en dudas por la manera en como leía el codigo para saber como era que estaba funcionando la condicion, Ya que pues no cuento con alguien que me explique quise aclarar esa duda Pero bueno Gracias y nada bendiciones!