# fallo al intentar que no se repita un numero aleatorio en arrays

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, bucles, while

Tengo este codigo ya casi terminado pero no consigo ver porque me repite los numeros aleatorios. He intendado ya de todo y no consigo ver lo que me falta. Alo mejor alguno me puede ayudar a solucionar esta duda que tengo. Estoy empezando asi que soy muy novata en esto todavia.El ejercicio es el siguiente:

Escribe un programa que genere al azar una combinación para jugar a la lotería
primitiva asegurándote de que ningún número se repite. Pista: puedes utilizar un array de 6 números enteros,
asignando a cada posición un número entero aleatorio entre 1 y 49, y comprobando que el número asignado no es igual a ninguno de los
asignados anteriormente.

```
    int num;
    int resultadoFinal = 0;
    boolean repetido= false;
    System.out.println("PROGRAMA PARA JUGAR A LA LOTERIA PRIMITIVA ");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    int loteria[]= new int[6]; //Definimos la array con la variable del tamaño
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
        //Generamos una posicion comprendida entre los valores de nuestro array
        int aleatorios = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*49)+1;
        for (int j = 0; j < loteria.length;j++) {
            while(loteria.equals(i)){
            aleatorios= (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*49)+1;
            }
        }
        loteria[i]= aleatorios;
        resultadoFinal=loteria[i]; 
    }
    System.out.println("Numero premiado:" ); // Pintamos por pantalla el tamaño total
    for(int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(loteria[i]); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Se parece a uno que resolví hace poco, aunque en javascript, pero la lógica del mismo te puede valer:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/509674/quisiera-que-no-se-me-repitieran-las-posiciones-de-los-corredores/509676#509676  (no se java, prefiero no intentar darte la respuesta directamente)

Comment: Notá que no siempre que generás el número aleatrorio estas recoriendo el array de los numeros que salieron para ver si ese número existe ya

Answer (score 0):

tal como te lo mencionan en lo comentarios,debes evaluar cada valor del array con el numero aleatorio que generes,espero te ayude

```
int num;
    int resultadoFinal = 0;
    boolean repetido= false;
    System.out.println("PROGRAMA PARA JUGAR A LA LOTERIA PRIMITIVA ");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
    int loteria[]= new int[6]; //Definimos la array con la variable del tamaño
    Random rnd = new Random();
  
    for(int j=0;j<loteria.length;j++){
            boolean encontrado = false;
            int aleatorio=(int)(Math.random()*49)+1;
            for (int k=0;k<j ;k++){
                if(loteria[k]==aleatorio){
                    encontrado=true;
                }
            }
            if(!encontrado){
                loteria[j]=aleatorio;
            }else{
                j--;
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Numero premiado:" ); // Pintamos por pantalla el tamaño total
    for(int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(loteria[i]); 
    }
```

Comment: El problema es que me lo pide para Java16 y no me funciona igual

Comment: @AliciaLópezTortosa edite mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Como comenté, con tu código no siempre recorres el array en su totalidad luego de generar un nuevo número.

Primero que nada ante estos tipos de problemas recomiendo siempre dividir la lógica lo más posible para reducir la complejidad.

Podrías crear un método que solamente se dedique a validar si el número que salió ya se encuentra en el array

```java
public boolean existe(int[] l, int num){
  for (int i=0; i<l.length;i++){
    if (l[i] == num)
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

De esta manera podrías intentar generar números hasta que sepas que  no salio llamando al método creado

```java
for (int i = 0; i < loteria.length; i++) {
  int aleatorios = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
  while (existe(loteria, aleatorios)){
    aleatorios = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
  }
  loteria[i]= aleatorios;
}
```

Notar que acorté el rango de números aleatorios de 49 a 6 para que sea mucho más facil encontrar casos que se repiten.